# DEPLOYMENTFOLDERS setting in .pro file not working

Tags: qt, qml

I am creating a QML Qt5 project, and want to automatically copy my qml files into the build folder when I click build.  I've edited my .pro file to include:

```
  qmlFolder.source = qml
  qmlFolder.target = .
  DEPLOYMENTFOLDERS += qmlFolder
  message("adding qml folder")
```

My project source folder structure is:

```
|
+-- build
+-- source
    |
    +--main.cpp
    |
    +--qml
        |
        +---main.qml
```

So when I click build I see the "adding qml folder" message in the Compile Output tab (in Qt creator) so I know make is reading the .pro file.  But the build folder is missing ANY qml files.  And I don't see any copy messages, or error message with build output.

Why isn't my DEPLOYMENTFOLDERS statement working?  (I'm compiling under Linux in case that matters)

The DEPLOYMENTFOLDERS directive is not well documented but should work as noted in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441129/how-to-use-deploymentfolders-directive-in-qt-widget-based-application)

Comment: Can you provide a link to the `DEPLOYMENTFOLDERS` documentation? I can't find anything about this parameter.

Comment: Isn't that a locally defined variable, looking at [Qt forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/61592/deploymentfolders-can-i-use-in-qt-5-5-1)?

Comment: It's an "undocumented" feature of Qt project files.  It is commonly used by Qt projects - but lots of criticism due to the lack of documentation

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that .pro feature is actually available in a deployment.pri file (which I failed to include).  Once incuded, and adding the qtcAddDeployment line to the .pro file, the feature worked as expected.

The important part of the .pri file is:

```
defineTest(qtcAddDeployment) {
for(deploymentfolder, DEPLOYMENTFOLDERS) {
    item = item$${deploymentfolder}
    greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4) {
        itemsources = $${item}.files
    } else {
        itemsources = $${item}.sources
    }
    $$itemsources = $$eval($${deploymentfolder}.source)
    itempath = $${item}.path
    $$itempath= $$eval($${deploymentfolder}.target)
    export($$itemsources)
    export($$itempath)
    DEPLOYMENT += $$item
}
}
```

Comment: I believe certain versions of Qt Creator would generate this code when you created a new project. So `DEPLOYMENTFOLDERS` is not actually a feature of `qmake`, but a convenience function that someone wrote to help with a common task. By the way, it's not necessary for the definition of `qtcAddDeployment` to be in its own .pri file. That just helps if you have a larger project with multiple .pro files which all might want to use this function.